# Token invalid - Invalid token: Unsupported token type 5

Tags: google-api, postman, google-oauth, google-email-audit-api

I'm working with G Suite Email Audit API.
After set up OAuth 2.0 token to acces the API; I had got the error when using this POST Request:

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Token invalid - Invalid token: Unsupported token type 5</TITLE>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
      <H1>Token invalid - Invalid token: Unsupported token type 5</H1>
      <H2>Error 401</H2>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

this is my request

```
https://apps-
apis.google.com/a/feeds/compliance/audit/mail/monitor/mydomaine/user
```

And the content type: 
    application/atom+xml

Answer (score 1):

You may need to pass the Access Token via a `GET` parameter.

For example, in the Picasa Web API I had used the following (note the `access_token` `GET` parameter instead of the `Authorisation` header):

`https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/userId?access_token=<access_token_here>`